# Why is it grammatically incorrect to say 'I watch much television' although it is an uncountable noun (in this context)?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, quantifiers

In the grammatically correct sentence, 'I watch a lot of television', the noun 'television' is an uncountable noun. However, it is grammatically incorrect to say 'I watch much television' with the quantifier 'much' for uncountable nouns. My students threw me off with this question and I was unable to answer it. Why is this the case?

Comment: It's certainly grammatical to say *I watch much television*, it's just not that common. Why do you say it is ungrammatical?

Comment: _Do you watch much television?_ or _I don't watch much television_ are highly idiomatic. _I watch much television_ is grammatically correct, but not likely produced by native speakers.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+television%2C+too+much+television%2C+a+lot+of+television&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmuch%20television%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20much%20television%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20of%20television%3B%2Cc0) indicates that 'much television' is more common than 'too much' or 'a lot of' but 'much television' in the Ngram may not refer to watching it but the content of it.

Comment: 'A lot of' is a more colloquial way to express an uncountable noun rather than 'much'. Unless one is saying 'too much'.

Comment: Will it sound better to say `I watch too much tv everyday.`?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of **style**. We usually use *a lot of* and *lots of* rather than *much* and *many* in informal affirmative clauses:

- *She gave me a lot of information.* (rather than *She gave me much information*).
- *I went shopping and spent a lot of money.* (rather than *I went shopping and spent much money*).

*Much* would sound too formal for the situations above. But it's not that *much television* is not grammatically correct.

Comment: It's not style or register, but usage.

Comment: To that, we can add consideration of the OP's observation that this isn't a count noun. With count nouns, too, "lots of" or "a lot of" or "a bunch of" tends to replace "many": "I watch a lot of sitcoms." "She gave me lots of leads." "I went shopping and wrote a bunch of checks." I'd be less inclined to use "many" in these, but it would be grammatical if I did.